# DataGridView Sort repositions the horizontal position of grid slightly

Tags: winforms, datagridview, .net-2.0

I have a DataGridView with a lot of columns which causes a horizontal scrollbar.  However, when I scroll all the way to the right and sort on a column the datagridview slightly repositions itself, but the scrollbar remains all the way to the right.

I want to stop this behavior and keep the grid in the same position it was in before the grid was sorted, and I would like to continue to use Automatic sorting in the grid if possible.

I found this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/48a5b6a4-d343-463c-8f31-4b5123a56c0a) and this person is having the same problem, however, the solution proposed there doesn't seem to be applicable since I am not doing manual sorting.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following.

I subscribed to the DataGridView.Scroll event, if the ScrollOrientation was Horizontal then I am setting a member variable to the NewValue of the scroll.

Then I subscribed to the DataGridView.Sorted event.  In this event I set the HorizontalScrollingOffset to the member variable.

```
int _horizontalOffsetStop;

private void Grid_Scrolled(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
     {
          _horizontalOffsetStop = e.NewValue;
     }
}

private void Grid_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     myGrid.HorizontalScrollingOffset = _horizontalOffsetStop;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working for me. Is there another Solution to this problem?